# gaemachanize: ImportError: No module named _winreg

Tags: google-app-engine

gaemechanize used to work fine when I try to do

```
import gaemechanize
```

. But recently, I updated GAE to newest version and I get this error when I run on local machine (gaemachanize works fine when upload to server)

```
Internal Server Error
import_string() failed for 'myapp.views.index'. Possible reasons are: - missing __init__.py in a package; - package or module path not included in sys.path; - duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path; - missing module, class, function or variable; Debugged import: - 'myapp' found in 'D:\\Dropbox\\GAE Proj\\xxxx\\myapp\\__init__.pyc'. - 'myapp.views' not found. Original exception: ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

I found `import _winreg` in _msiecookiejar.py file in gaemechanize

I am using python 2.7.7 on windows 7

I got error when I try to do

```
pip install _winreg
```

How to fix it?